# How to fix star rating css and html

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

So basically I have a ionic mobile application. One of the many modules in the app is the review and ratings. So by implementing such module, I added stars in which a user can click whether he wants to rate a certain user by tapping one star to five stars. So the problem here is that, once a choose a certain star, example 5 then he taps other parts in the app the stars will be gone.

[image]

After choosing a star:
[image]

and the user taps other than the star rating, the star choosen will be gone. How to fix such error?

Code below:
        html

```
    <div class="rating">
<!-- <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon> -->
<span (click)="rate(5)">☆</span>
<span (click)="rate(4)">☆</span>
<span (click)="rate(3)">☆</span>
<span (click)="rate(2)">☆</span>
<span (click)="rate(1)">☆</span>
```

```
CSS

 page-review {
   .rating {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

  }



   .rating>span:hover:before {
   content: "\2605";
     position: absolute;
  }

 .rating {
   unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
   }
  .rating>span:hover:before,
  .rating>span:hover~span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
  }

  .rating {
   unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  }
 .rating>span {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #F2AF01;
  }
  .rating>span:hover:before,
  .rating>span:hover~span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
  }

  p{
  font-size: 20px;
 }

  .review-description{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
}
```

Comment: are you storing those stars? somewhere?

Comment: It is not working for me at all. Lately, I needed to develop star rating too, and I've found [this](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh), pure CSS one, which I recommend.

Comment: no im am not nihal :)

Comment: really mpro? ill take a look at  the link

Comment: but im hoping there's a solution for this its been a while since ive been debugging

Comment: hi mpro. i tried the link you said bu still facing the same issues

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ionic-ratings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-ratings)

when you do all steps to install and import then you can use it like

```
  $scope.ratingsObject = {
    iconOn: 'ion-ios-star',    //Optional 
    iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',   //Optional 
    iconOnColor: 'rgb(200, 200, 100)',  //Optional 
    iconOffColor:  'rgb(200, 100, 100)',    //Optional 
    rating:  2, //Optional 
    minRating:1,    //Optional 
    readOnly: true, //Optional 
    callback: function(rating, index) {    //Mandatory 
      $scope.ratingsCallback(rating, index);
    }
  };

  $scope.ratingsCallback = function(rating, index) {
    console.log('Selected rating is : ', rating, ' and the index is : ', index);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using :hover and a **really interesting** combination of inverted HTML order and text direction switching in order to use the `~` general sibling selector to fill the previous stars, which is awesome.

But you're making so by using CSS :hover, which is really meant for when the mouse hovers an element on desktop. As soon as the pointer leaves, the :hover state ends, and therefore, any style that was applied on hover by CSS will go away.

On mobile, there's no really :hover state as theres no mouse pointer to begin with, but some engines use the taps instead.. but then again, when you tap anywhere else, the "pointer" will no longer be over the element, so the :hover state ends.

I'm not familiar with ionic, but it seems you'll need to modify whatever your rate() method is (or add another method on click) to display the current value.

A simple approach from the CSS point of view would be to use a CSS "selected" class identical to the :hover state, which you would add to the selected element on click (and remove from the others if present).

From the CSS point of view, should be something like this:

```
 .rating>span.selected:before,
  .rating>span.selected~span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
  }
```

To keep it DRY, you might just add it on the same rule as you're setting the hovers

```
.rating>span:hover:before,
.rating>span:hover~span:before,
.rating>span.selected:before,
.rating>span.selected~span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
  }
```

BTW, you have 2 identical copies of your .rating and .rating>span:hover~span:before rules, and 3 identical copies of .rating>span:hover:before  rule, you might want to clean that as well.

Comment: hi sorry about the identical copies forgot to delete. thank you for explaining in depth what the problem is.  i tried what you said but still facing the same issue :((((. please help me

Comment: @Jennica have you set the javascript to add the .selected classes onclick?

Comment: no i havent.what do you mean set the javascript sir facundo?

Comment: where should i put the .selected classes in the html sir facundo?

Comment: Let's see... set the rule for the `.selected` as I stated in the answer, and use `<span class="selected">☆</span>` on any of your spans, just as a test to see if it works

Comment: on the actual production code, you shouldn't have the `.selected` class on your html, but dinamically set it at runtime on the clicked element, if that's possible

Comment: if you added it before all others, then that's what I was trying to test :p

Comment: :P okay. so what should we propably do sir do make it correct?

Comment: looks like it will work, you just have figure how to dynamically add the class onclick on the selected item at runtime.